# React Redux not having context

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-dom

Working on react web & using react-redux, facing an error (please refer below screenshot). When building application no errors, only navigates to that route getting it. Looks like `this.props` is not having access to redux context.
Don't know what am missing?

Same implementation is working fine for another component to list all users.

[image]

[image]

**Products.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { GetAllProducts } from "../../redux/actions/ProductsActions";

export class Products extends Component {
   componentDidMount() {
      this.props.GetAllProducts();
   }
   render() {
      return (
         <div className="col-span-12">
            {(this.props.allProducts || []).map((product) => {
               return <div>{product.productName}</div>;
            })}
         </div>
      );
   }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
   status: state.Products.status,
   allProducts: state.Products.productList || [],
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
   return {
      GetAllProducts: () => dispatch(GetAllProducts("products")),
   };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Products);
```

**ProductsActions.js**

```
import * as actions from "../actions/ActionTypes";
import axios from "axios";

export const GetAllProducts = (catagory) => {
   return (dispatch) => {
      dispatch({ type: actions.GET_PRODUCT_LIST_PENDING });

      axios
         .get(`http://localhost:5000/api/get/${catagory}`)
         .then((res) => {
            dispatch({
               type: actions.GET_PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
               payload: res.data,
            });
         })
         .catch((err) => {
            dispatch({
               type: actions.GET_PRODUCT_LIST_FAILURE,
               payload: err,
            });
         });
   };
};
```

Comment: Can you share the piece of code where you are using `Product`? you are exporting both `Product` and `connect(..,..)(Product)`, so my guess is that you imported the wrong component.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @El Aoutar Hamza, I've imported like this

**Old code:**

```
import { Products } from "./Products";
```

**New code - Resolved**

```
import Products from "./Products";
```

By removing the curly brackets the issue got resolved.